# Simplifying cyclometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How does one simplify this function?
$$ f ( x ) = \arccos \left( \frac { \pi } { 2 } - \sin ( x ) \right) $$

A plot in GeoGebra showed a graph that looked like semicircle:

[image]

so can one expect something in this form:  $\space\sqrt{(a - (x + d)^2} $ ?

Comment: It is not a semicircle.   In particular, it is not an algebraic function of $x$.

Comment: i got this here $\frac{1}{2} \left(\pi -2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \sin
   (x))\right)\right)$

Comment: Are you certain you don't mean $f(x)=\pi/2 -\arccos (\sin x)$?

Comment: For most values of $x$ the function $f(x)$ is not even defined, since the argument of the $arccos$ will often be larger than $1$.

Comment: At last it was the function that Dr. MV suggested. Bad blackboard copying. Thanks all for suggestions.